# select row containing links and buttons in table by clicking anywhere on the row

Tags: angularjs, row

I have an AngularJS application managing contacts. The main page contents the list of contacts with a table with different rows. When the user clicks anywhere on the row (except the link for editing and the button for deleting the contact in the last column), he has to be redirected on a section (contact details) of my page.

I tried to do that. It's working but my button for deleting the contact is not working. How can I get that button to work?

Here is my template:

```
<table ng-show="contacts.length" class="table table-striped table-hover spacer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="colPerson">
        <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('PERSON')">Person</a>
        <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('PERSON')"></span>
      </th>
      <th class="colCompany">
        <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('COMPANY')">Company</a>
        <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('COMPANY')"></span>
      </th>
      <th class="colDate">
        <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('REQUESTTRUEDATE')">Date</a>
        <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('REQUESTTRUEDATE')"></span>
      </th>
      <th class="colDescription">
        <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')">Description</a>
        <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')"></span>
      </th>
      <th class="colAction">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText | orderBy:champTri:triDescendant" ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)">
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td class="colPerson" ng-class="{sel:selIdx==$index}"><a href="#/view-contacts/{{contact.ID}}">{{contact.PERSON}}</a></td>
      <td class="colCompany">{{contact.COMPANY}}</td>
      <td class="colDate">{{contact.REQUESTTRUEDATE | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      <td class="colDescription">{{contact.REQUESTDESCRIPTION}}</td>
      <td class="colNbRequest">{{contact.NBREQUEST}}</td>

      <td class="colAction">
        <a href="#/edit-contacts/{{contact.ID}}" class="inline btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
        <button class="inline btn btn-default" data-ng-click="confirmDelPerson(contact.ID)">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If I click anywhere on the row the page for seeing details is displayed. 
If I click in the last column on the link for editing the page for editing, it is equally working.
But if I click on the button for deleting it is not working (the page for seeing details appears).

Here is a part of my controller:

```
app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, ContactService) {
  $scope.contacts = null;
  $scope.searchButtonText = "Search";
  $scope.test = false;
  $scope.reSearch = function () {
    // simulate search
    $timeout(function () {
      // search is complete
    }, 2000);
  }
  $scope.search = function (searchText) {
    if (!searchText.length) {
      //alert("searchText empty");
    }
    if (searchText.length > 2) {
      $scope.loading = true;
      $scope.test = true;
      $scope.searchButtonText = "Loading...";
      ContactService.fastSearch(searchText).success(function (contacts) {
        var length = contacts.length;
        $scope.loading = false;
        if (length == 0) {
          $scope.searchButtonText = "No result";
        } else {
          $scope.searchButtonText = length + " results found";
        }
        // For the orderby date
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if (contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE != "") {
            contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE = new Date(contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE.replace(/-/g, "/"));
          } else {
            contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE = null;
          }
        }
        $scope.contacts = contacts;
        $scope.champTri = 'PERSON';
        $scope.selIdx = -1;
        $scope.selContact = function (contact, idx) {
          $scope.selectedContact = contact;
          $scope.selIdx = idx;
          window.location = "#/view-contacts/" + idx;
        }
        $scope.isSelContact = function (contact) {
          return $scope.selectedContact === contact;
        }
      });
    } else {
      $scope.contacts = null;
    }
  }
  // recherche
  $scope.searchText = null;
  $scope.razRecherche = function () {
    $scope.searchText = null;
  }
  // tri
  $scope.champTri = null;
  $scope.triDescendant = false;
  $scope.personsSort = function (champ) {
    if ($scope.champTri == champ) {
      $scope.triDescendant = !$scope.triDescendant;
    } else {
      $scope.champTri = champ;
      $scope.triDescendant = false;
    }
  }
  $scope.cssChevronsTri = function (champ) {
    return {
      glyphicon: $scope.champTri == champ,
      'glyphicon-chevron-up': $scope.champTri == champ && !$scope.triDescendant,
      'glyphicon-chevron-down': $scope.champTri == champ && $scope.triDescendant
    };
  }
  $scope.confirmDel = function (id) {
    if (confirm('Do you want to delete this contact?')) {
      ContactService.delContact(id).success(function () {
        ContactService.getContact().success(function (contacts) {
          $scope.contacts = contacts;
        });
      });
    }
    $scope.orderby = orderby;
  };
});
```

Comment: What does confirm('Do you want to delete this contact?') return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be this

```
<tbody ... ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)">
```

Try to put this ng-click in the `<td>` tags.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText | orderBy:champTri:triDescendant" >
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)" class="colPerson" ng-class="{sel:selIdx==$index}"><a href="#/view-contacts/{{contact.ID}}">{{contact.PERSON}}</a></td>
      <td ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)" class="colCompany">{{contact.COMPANY}}</td>
      <td ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)" class="colDate" >{{contact.REQUESTTRUEDATE | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      <td ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)" class="colDescription">{{contact.REQUESTDESCRIPTION}}</td>
      <td ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)" class="colNbRequest">{{contact.NBREQUEST}}</td>

      <td class="colAction">
        <a href="#/edit-contacts/{{contact.ID}}" class="inline btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
        <button class="inline btn btn-default" data-ng-click="confirmDelPerson(contact.ID)">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Also I recommend you to use flex and not the `<table>` tag, I've had a lot of problems with this tag.